# jQuery slideshow in background and print.css

Tags: jquery

i am using slideshow script for background. Its working excelent on website itself but its not good on printed paper. I can always see background no metter what. I just want simple white background on paper.

Script used  Vegas background slideshow.

http://tinyurl.com/cwhpjej

Comment: that link goes to http://www.itchyfeet.biz/ which does not appear to have a slideshow, sure hope I'm missing something and you are not spamming. if in fact you are looking for help then don't post url's to a sites (that's sure fire way to get yourself viewed as a scammer), instead post code snippets, and possibly in your case an image of the print out.

Comment: Slideshow is in page background :) its rotating few images. But i just want to remove that option for print. Can i force javascript to load for all devices except for print?

Comment: ah i see. please show the javascript / html / css code so we can easily see what is involved, check this for tips for posting questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  i for one admit i'm not going to evlauate code on an external site initially, just code snippet posted in the question. however a likely answer is use css - @media print { .the-class-of-the-div-containing-the-slideshow { display:none; } }